# How can we make horizontal scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I need to add horizontal scrollbar. It should have same interface for all browsers and compatible with android, windows, tablets etc.

Comment: Anything you tried? Hint: CSS will help

Comment: i tried alot i have got from css but they they are not working on opera browser and from jquery issue of browser compatibilty.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qzg63svq/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/517kkpdL/        this one is second

Comment: When I tried your second fiddle using Opera, it works fine...You are not able to see scroll bar itself?

Comment: yes in desktop it's working fine but when we see in android mobile we won't be able to see that.

Answer (score 0):

Customize the scrollbar and make it cross-browser it's still complicated with full CSS.

Webkit-based browser make the customisation possible with CSS only as you do. But your snippet doesn't work even on Firefox, for example.

Maybe you should have a look to some JS plugins, in particular [this one](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) what I had to use in the past.

[Demo](http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/complete_examples.html)

Don't be afraid with the theme, you can create yours. You'll find a tutorial to do it [here](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/#styling-section).

Hope this helped you, even if it's not a full-CSS solution but this is the only way I know to deal with stylised scrollbar.